# Django : Get the highest queryset attribute in my template

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm beginning with Django and I would like to know how I can get attributs from my Django queryset.

I have this queryset :

```
get_country = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).values('country__name').order_by('country__name').annotate(count_country=Count('country__name'))
```

It returns :

```
<QuerySet [{'country__name': 'France', 'count_country': 1}, {'country__name': 'Germany', 'count_country': 2}]>
```

So I would like to display in my template the country name with the highest `count_country`

I would like to know how I can do that ?

Thank you so much

Comment: So you are only interested in the `Country` with the most `Download`s?

Comment: Yes exactly and get the name from the most downloaded country ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better query this the reverse way, like:

```
max_country = Country.objects.filter(
    download__pub__publication__id=pubsd.id
).annotate(
    ndown=Count('download')
).order_by('-ndown').first()
```

(with `download` here the `related_name` of the `Country` to `Download` relation).

This will give you the `Country` object with the most related `Download`s, you can then do processing or rendering on the `Country` object, like you can do with any `Country` object.

If you for example pass the object to the template, you can render it like:

```
Most downloads are from {{ max_country.name }}
```

Comment: I tried your queryset and I added `related_name` to Download model but it doesn't display the good result. For a given publication, I have 2 Germany and 1 France and it gives me "France". So not the highest country. Hum I have to see why ;)

Comment: Ok i understood why, it's because in my queryset I set filter over specific publication. I have to handle your queryset with my filter. But I hope it will not be so hard. So your queryset doesn't work for the moment. And I can't add filter as previously in yours because you are requeting over Country and not Download ?

Comment: @user10390326: hmm.. Does adding the filter helps?

Comment: Yes perfect ! I forgot `download` in `download__pub__publication__id=pubsd.id` that's why it didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

in view

```
return render(request,'template.html','{'country':'get_country'}
```

in template

```
{% for key, values in country.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{values }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}


get_country = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).values('country__name').order_by('country__name').annotate(count_country=Count('country__name')).order_by('-count_country')
```

Comment: Without running your code, I assume it doesn't return the hisghest country

Comment: it depends on the queryset that you generated. for that i gave the code, else try the queryset in my answer

Comment: I tried the queryset in your answer but I didn't get the expected result. But thank you with your comment !